# Self in type parameter outside of struct in Rust

Tags: types, rust, traits

I am working on some patterns like this:

```
trait FooThis {
    type Foo;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Foo;
}
struct SomeFooImpl<T: FooThis>(fn(&mut T));

trait Foo {}
impl<T: FooThis> Foo for SomeFooImpl<T> {}
struct Bar<T: Foo>(T);
impl<T: Foo> FooThis for Bar<T> {
    type Foo = T;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::Foo {
        &self.0
    }
}

// type B = Bar<SomeFooImpl<B>>;
```

Basically, there are lots of structs implement `Foo` like `SomeFooImpl`, and a set of structs implements `FooThis` like `Bar`, and I want to make all combinations work.

So the problem here is when I try to initiate a `impl FooThis` such as `Bar` with `SomeFooImpl`, I need the type that I am initiating appears in the parameter list. I cannot use `Self` to achieve it because it is not inside of `Bar` (or anything implements `FooThis`) definition. Wrapping `Bar` to hide the type parameter will also make it unable to implement `FooThis`, so I cannot do that either.

One potential solution is to eliminate type parameter of `SomeFooImpl` by changing the function pointer to `fn(&mut dyn FooThis)`, but I am trying to avoid it.

Is there a static-dispatching way to solve it? Everything except `Foo` and `FooThis` traits are modifiable.

Comment: This is an infinite self-recursive type, which Rust does not support.

`type B = Bar<SomeFooImpl<Bar<SomeFooImpl<Bar<SomeFooImpl< ... >>>>>>;`